# Historical Summer Olympics Medal Counts?

Tags: data-request, sports

Anyone have a file/group of files containing medal counts by country over time? The past few aren't hard to get, but before that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project of files here: https://www.datazar.com/project/p5d33ef20-3df6-4a71-94e4-59123f16add6 on Datazar, containing medal counts from Summer Olympics from 1896-2008. The last two shouldn't be hard to get though, I will search around and add them to the project.

Full discolusre: I work at Datazar- A collaborative open data library